# Monastic nerd takes a leave from seclusion into the profane world

Tags: story-identification

I seem to remember the science-fiction novel or short story is younger than 20 years old. The material was definitely published in English and I was reading a digital copy on the Web.

The start of the story goes like: A monastic nerd takes a leave from seclusion into the profane world and is in awe of the strangeness of it all around him. He points a [tricorder](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tricorder#Noun) at cops who feel threatened and proceed to tackle him and rough him up a bit.

Comment: Hey daxim... by 'tricorder' do you mean 'futuristic handheld sensor package' or do you specifically mean 'futuristic **Starfleet™** handheld sensor package'?

Comment: https://www.tor.com/2008/08/06/weak-and-strange/?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This sounds like Cory Doctorow's piece "The Things that Make Me Weak and Strange Get Engineered Away", published (exclusively, as far as I can tell) on [tor.com](https://www.tor.com/2008/08/06/weak-and-strange/).

The story begins with a member of a monastic order, if a monastic order was also a Google datacenter:

> From the nearby cubicles, Lawrence heard the ritualized muttering of a thousand brothers and sisters in the Order of Reflective Analytics, a susurration of harmonized, concentrated thought.

He is sent into the outside world to find another member of the order who has vanished from their campus.

> “I know it’s been getting worse out there—”
>
> The old timer barked a laugh. “Not your thing? It’s probably time you got out into the wide world, son."

The order obsessively scans and logs *everything* in their campus. He tries to keep doing so outside of the campus and it doesn't go so well.

> As he raised the lifelogger, the officer closest to him reached out with serpentine speed and snatched it out of his hands, power-assisted fingers coming together on it with a loud, plasticky crunk as the device shattered into a rain of fragments. Just as quickly, the other officer had come around the vehicle and seized Lawrence’s wrists, bringing them together in a painful, machine-assisted grip.

Answer (score 12):

It might very well be Anathem by Neal Stephenson.

It's most certainly some nerdy 'monastic' person venturing outside into, and there are several scuffles due to misunderstanding and/or other issues in there. The only  thing is I can't specifically remember a tricorder-like thing to be fair.

(obviously not a 'short story')

Comment: *"obviously not a 'short story'"* - Anathem was one of the first books I read on an e-reader. It took me quite a while to realize how far it was from a short story.

Comment: @GregorThomas - Heh. The perils of the modern age. When you see its ponderous bulk lurking on a bookstore or library shelf, its pretty obvious at a glance.